# Combinatorics Urn Problem?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Technically, yes, this is homework.  I'm not asking you to give me the answer, I just need to know what I'm doing wrong.  The problem is:

A student studies 15 problems from which the professor will randomly choose 4 for a quiz.  If the student can solve 12 out of the 15 problems, what is the probability that she can only solve at most 2 of the problems on the quiz?

Since she can only solve at most 2 problems, I know that means P(solve 0) + P(solve 1) +P(solve 2).

Through some series of steps that I can't quite remember I translated that into
$$\frac{(C_{12,0})( C_{3,4})}{C_{15,4}} + \frac{(C_{12,1})( C_{3,3})}{C_{15,4}}+\frac{(C_{12,2})( C_{3,2})}{C_{15,4}}$$

However, I don't know how to compute $$C_{3,4}$$
because I don't know how to do one of those when the first number is smaller than the second number.  So I feel like I must be doing something wrong here.

Comment: *"I know that means P(solve 0) + P(solve 1) +P(solve 2)."* Shouldn't there be an equality sign in there some where or something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How many ways of choosing $4$ different items from a set of $3$? None, so let your $C_{3,4}=0$

Turning this more into your actual question, if you know the answers to $12$ of the $15$ questions, there is no way (barring errors) that you will get $4$ different questions wrong.  So you need $\frac{(C_{12,0})( C_{3,4})}{C_{15,4}}=0$ though you know $C_{12,0}=1$ and $C_{15,4}=1365$

Comment: Thanks.  Now, thinking about it, I realize how it wouldn't make sense to get 0 of the problems solved.